# Data binding - sub object is not converted to secure object under Locker Service

Tags: lightning-aura-components, locker-service

I'm facing a really strange issue

I have an attribute defined in my lightning component:

```
<aura:attribute name="item" type="Object"/>
```

This object is fetched from server in the `init` call with a pretty standard mechanism:

**Controller code:**

```
helper.loadItem(component)
```

**Helper code:**

```
loadItem : function(component) {

    var actionItem = component.get("c.getQuoteItem");
    actionItem.setParams({ "quoteItemId": component.get("v.itemId") });
    var self = this;

    actionItem.setCallback(this, function(a) {
        var state = a.getState();
        if (state === "SUCCESS") {
            var response = JSON.parse(a.getReturnValue());

            if (response.status == "SUCCESS") {
                var item = JSON.parse(response.data);
                this.setInitialAttributeValues(component, item);
                component.set("v.item", item);
            } else if (response.status == "ERROR") {
                ...
            }
        ...
     }
```

`item` object is quite complex object with multiple nested objects as properties. Especially `item.attributes` is an object that is a map of objects like below:

```
item.attributes.ATR_TESTATTRIBUTE_ = {attributeValue: {value: 'test'}, ...}
item.attributes.ATR_NAMEOFOTHERATTRIBUTE_ = {...}
```

These map of `item.attributes` map does not usually come from server, but is initialized in `this.setInitialAttributeValues(component, item);` method in helper (just after getting data from server, but before calling first `component.set`).

After having Locker Service turned on I can see that not all of them are being converted to secure objects, therefore they are not visible to the application at later stages.

This is how `item` looks as secure object - top level looks good. Triple dots mean getters and setters were properly initialised:

[image: This is how secure object - top level looks like. Triple dots mean getters and setters were properly initialised]

But if I expand `attributes` property - nested objects don't have any getters and setters (no triple dots). They're just plain objects. Therefore they behave like they are not visible to the application in further methods.

[image: Expanded attributes property]

I tried different workarounds I heard in the past - here like calling `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify())` but it doesn't seem to work. Any idea what may be happening?

**EDIT - NARROWED DOWN SCENARIO**

I have created a narrowed scenario of that problem and it seems that framework has problem with adding new properties to existing variables. Example below:

**Apex Class: XXX_MASIM_TestLockerLC**

```
public with sharing class XXX_MASIM_TestLockerLC {

    @auraEnabled
    public static String getObjWrapper() {
        ObjWrapper result = new ObjWrapper();
        result.name = 'test';
        result.attributes = new Map<String, SubObjWrapper>();
        result.attributes.put('ATR_ATR1_', new SubObjWrapper('test', 'test'));
        result.attributes.put('ATR_ATR2_', new SubObjWrapper('test2', 'test2'));
        return JSON.serialize(result);
    }

    public class ObjWrapper {
        public String name {get;set;}
        public Map<String, SubObjWrapper> attributes {get;set;}
    }

    public class SubObjWrapper {
        public String label {get;set;}
        public String value {get;set;}

        public SubObjWrapper(String label, String value) {
            this.label = label;
            this.value = value;
        }
    }

}
```

**Component**

```
<aura:component controller="XXX_MASIM_TestLockerLC">
    <aura:attribute name="testObj" type="Object"/>
    <aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.initialize}"/>
</aura:component>
```

**Component Controller**

```
({
    initialize : function(component, event, helper) {
        helper.loadObjWrapper(component);
    }
})
```

**Component Helper**

loadObjWrapper function is responsible for fetching object from server. Before calling `component.set` it passes the object through another helper function to add additional properties

```
({
    loadObjWrapper : function(component) {
        var actionItem = component.get("c.getObjWrapper");
        var self = this;

        actionItem.setCallback(this, function(a) {
            var state = a.getState();

            if (state === "SUCCESS") {
                var testObj = JSON.parse(a.getReturnValue());
                console.log(testObj);
                this.addAdditionalAttributes(component, testObj);
                component.set("v.testObj", testObj);
                console.log(component.get("v.testObj"));
            }
        });
        $A.enqueueAction(actionItem);
    },

    addAdditionalAttributes : function(component, item) {
        var placeholder1 = {'name': 'test3', 'value': 'test3'};
        var placeholder2 = {'name': 'test4', 'value': 'test4'};

        item.attributes['ATR_ATR3_'] = placeholder1;
        item.attributes['ATR_ATR4_'] = placeholder2;

        console.log(item);
    }
})
```

When I console.log the object it looks like properties were only properly converted to secure object for those properties that came from server. Properties that were added by `addAdditionalAttributes` function are not properly converted to Secure Object - they don't have getters and setters.

[image: Properties that were not converted to Secure Object]

**Case number: #16215426**